# Does giving an item to someone else count as a visit?

Tags: werewolv.es

I've been told that when you give an item to another person, that person won't know who sent it. But does giving an item to someone else count as a visit? Could a stalker or a harlot see it?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of answering this, item transfers are not visible visits, and not seen by role or item. This also means they do not count as a visit that will trigger an Omegawolf kill. Although this may change at some point in the future.

This has even caught me out in the past, and I coded the bloody thing! ;)